# Do I need to configure Log4Net in every window or is there a way to do it once in a base class?

Tags: c#, wpf, log4net

Any examples I've seen look something like this:

```
ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MainWindow));
```

I don't like the idea of having copy/pasted code all over the place doing essentially the same thing.

Ideally I could configure the logger in some base class and configure Log4Net like follows:

```
public ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyWindowBase));
```

and have all windows inherit from that. The problem I can see with this is that MainWindow is defined as

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {}
```

so it already inherits from `Window`.

I thought of doing the following:

```
public partial class MyBase : Window
{
    // configure Log4Net here
}

public partial class MainWindow : MyBase
{
    // use Log4Net here
}
```

but this doesn't work. I get the following error:

> Partial declarations of 'WpfApplication3.MainWindow' must not specify different base classes

So what I'm wondering is there a good solid way of doing this that doesn't require configuring Log4Net in every window?

**edit** to clarify that the issue is not with creating the base class, the issue is that I want to know the best way to configure Log4Net without having to add this

```
ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(/* Window Type */));
```

in every class.

Comment: i do not think what error your getting has any thing to do with log4net. Plus by definition, at compile time your 2 partial classes will be merged to 1. So its not allowed

Comment: thy [this solution](http://blog.peterlesliemorris.com/archive/2009/07/23/partial-declarations-of-must-not-specify-different-base-classes.aspx)

Comment: @zenwalker, yes I understand that. I'm just showing an example of what issue I'm faced with trying to create a base class to configure it. The question is how to do it.

Comment: @DaveDev then your asking 2 different questions which is very confusing in the first place. Change your inheritance heirarchy. Multiple inheritance isnt allowed in C#. Create a base class add Log4net def (inititalize,etc.) in its ctor. That way its always gets inititalized by itself or by child classes.

Answer (score 2):

It is very common to configure log4net loggers as follows:

```
class MyClass
{
    private static ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass)); 
    ...
}
```

This creates a logger with the same name as the class, which is handy if you want to be able to selectively enable logging based on the logger name.

Note the use of a static field, so that the overhead of instantiating the logger is only incurred once, not each time the class is instantiated.

Of course the flexibility of being able to selectively enable logging comes at a cost: you will have to have a similar declaration in each class that does logging.

I don't see any way round this unless you are willing to give up the ability to selectively enable logging, in which case you can route all logging requests through a single global logger, e.g.:

```
public static class LoggingHelper
{
    public static ILog GlobalLogger
    {
        get { return _globalLogger; }
    }
    private static ILog _globalLogger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("Global"); 
}
```

You can also combine these approaches: for example you can use a global logger when logging exceptions (it's unlikely that you'd want to selectively disable logging of exceptions), and a class-specific logger in some of your classes for Debug logging (which you may well want to selectively enable / disable).

In response to comment:

> What are the benefits of selectively enabling logging?

IMHO the main benefit is when you want [instrumentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_%28computer_programming%29).  You can do this by liberally sprinkling Debug level logging statements throughout the parts of your code base you want to instrument.  Because such logging tends to be verbose, it's nice to be able to selectively enable only those bits you want to examine, for example when troubleshooting.

Comment: The reason I'm using Log4Net is to log errors as they occur in my `catch{}` blocks, so I want this to be available everywhere. As such, I don't see any issues with your approach. What are the benefits of selectively enabling logging?

Answer (score 0):

I use a static class

```
public static class lgr
{
#region "log4Net"
private static bool _isInfoEnabled = false;
private static bool _isWarnEnabled = false;
private static bool _isDebugEnabled = false;
private static ILog _logger;
public static ILog Logger {
    get {
        if ((_logger == null)) {
            _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("root");
            _isInfoEnabled = _logger.IsInfoEnabled;
            _isWarnEnabled = _logger.IsWarnEnabled;
            _isDebugEnabled = _logger.IsDebugEnabled;
        }
        return _logger;
    }
    set {
        if ((value == null)) {
            _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.DeclaringType);
        } else {
            _logger = value;
        }
    }
}

public static string LoggerName {
    get { return Logger.Logger.Name; }
    set {
        if (value == null || value == string.Empty) {
            Logger = null;
        } else {
            Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(value);
        }
    }
}

public enum LogType
{
    Debug,
    Info,
    Warn,
    Error_,
    Fatal
}
public static void WriteLogError(string _message, Exception ex)
{
    if (Logger.IsErrorEnabled) {
        Logger.Error(_message, ex);
    }
}

public static void WriteLogInfo(string _message)
{
    if (_isInfoEnabled) {
        Logger.Info(_message);
    }
}

public static void WriteLogWarn(string _message)
{
    if (_isWarnEnabled) {
        Logger.Warn(_message);
    }
}
#endregion
```

}

then i use it from everywhere in the app

```
if (Logger.IsInfoEnabled()) {
    Logger.Info("Processing...");
}
```

And also

```
WriteLogInfo(string.Format("Close time:{0}", _closeDateTime));
```

Comment: By storing `_logger.IsDebugEnabled` in a static field, you lose the ability to dynamically change the configuration to enable more detailed logging at runtime (e.g. using Log4Net's `ConfigureAndWatch` method.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it completely addresses your concerns but you can use:

```
ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(
               System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

then at least this way the code is identical in every instance rather having to use:

```
ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(/* Window Type */));
```